# Remove trailing .0 from API returned `double`

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

I am calling an `XML` API that as part of its array returns a number, or a combination of letters and numbers, i.e. `702` or '''RA3'''.

It returns numbers, but adds `.0` to the end, despite the call viewed in a web browser returning whole numbers such as `702`, whilst my parse below returns `702.0`

It also returns `null` to any that contain a letter, presumably this is because my method is a `double`, but I cant find a way around it.

My current method to parse it is as follows

```
class VehicleActivity {
  VehicleActivity({

    this.publishedLineName,

  double? publishedLineName;

        publishedLineName: 
            double.tryParse(vaElement.findAllElements('PublishedLineName').first.text)
...
```

I call the API in a separate method which works fine and then take the data with this

```
for (var vehicleActivity in vehicleActivity) {
var pln = vehicleActivity.publishedLineName.toString; //this is the problem line, I have tried all sorts of adaptations to it.
...
```

The actual API returns whole numbers, such as `702`, but when I call this data from my method it returns `702.0`. Also, any with letters are `null`, I guess because its a double.

I have tried every single method I can find online and none have worked. Thank you.

Update RH

I have looked into the XML returned and it returns values back such as...

```
lutter: 656.0
flutter: 53.0
flutter: null
2 flutter: 7.0
2 flutter: 702.0
flutter: 8.0
flutter: 3.0
flutter: 7.0
```

null being values such as `RA1`, which when I use to `hashcode`, 7.0 comes back as 7, but RA1 goes from `null` to `2011`

I would like them be to returned without decimal places such as 7, 702, RA1, with letters included. These ideally would end up as a String, as thy are going into a List. But anyway to get the proper values back without null and `.0` can be worked with. Thank you

Comment: Forget what a browser shows; it's possibly further interpreting the XML - only believe what you see in a print statement or looking at the XML in a text editor. Update the question with snippets of the XML showing the integer and non-integer values and state how you'd like to see them in you code (kept as int, kept as String, etc).

Comment: All doubles have a value behind the decimal. that's what makes it a double. Othewise it would be an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
double? publishedLineName;

        publishedLineName: 
            double.tryParse(vaElement.findAllElements('PublishedLineName').first.text)
```

to this:

```
String? publishedLineName;

        publishedLineName: 
            vaElement.findAllElements('PublishedLineName').first?.text
```

Comment: That has done it,```.first?.text``` threw an error that the ```?``` wasn't needed so I removed and works perfectly, thank you very much!